# Add google drive images to README.md on GitHub

Tags: github, markdown

Recently I joined GitHub. I am hosted some projects there.

I need to include some my GoogleDrive images in my README File. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've told us what you don't know, but not what you _do_ know, or what you've tried. Do you know how to add images in general? Have you searched for how? Have you tried linking to your images on Google Drive using that general strategy? What happened? Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

First, get a share-able link to your Google Drive image so anyone can view it.

Then, the GitHub-flavored markdown for an image is what you're looking for:

```
![optional-description-here](link-here)
```

This is the syntax for an image to be loaded from a link.  My favorite example:

```
![StackOverflow logo](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/hubfs/B2B-SO/images/logo-so-PRINT-4.png)
```

I even added a public example for you [here on my GitHub](https://gist.github.com/theshteves/31c9508e05d8f2b98426b2d29e72ba57)